# How to semi-automate webpage in watir?

Tags: ruby, watir

I am using Ruby with Watir to open irctc webpage. I can enter username and password automatically.
     When It comes to CAPTCHA, I can not use any syntax to enter a CAPTCHA. Because I do not know what it will be beforehand. I just want a simple method in which I can enter CAPTCHA by hand. While entering CAPTCHA my script should wait, then It should execute next syntax from script.

```
#require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'watir'

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox
caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = true
driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for(:firefox, desired_capabilities: caps)
browser = Watir::Browser.new(driver)

# text to show on console
puts "Beginning of the automation of IRCTC webpage"

browser.goto("https://www.irctc.co.in/eticketing/loginHome.jsf")

#browser.button(:id, "returnButton").click

#set a variable
search_text = "my_username"

#puts " Step 2: enter "+ search_text +" in the search text field."
browser.text_field(:name, "j_username").set search_text # "j_username" is the name of the search field

#browser.span(:class, "RveJvd snByac").click # "RveJvd snByac" is the class-name of the Search button

search_text = "my_password"
browser.text_field(:name, "j_password").set search_text

#Here I need to enter CAPTCHA before proceeding to next syntax.

browser.button(:type, "submit").click
```

Comment: I have automated IRCTC website, I faced the same problem, what I do here is, I put a debug pointer on the login button and once program reach the debug pointer, I manually enter and then I press F9 key to proceed further and it would stop in the next debug pointer

Comment: CAPTCHA can't be read because it's a image.

Comment: How is the script being executed?

Comment: @RAJ Looks like you got my point. How do you put debug pointer? You can write it as the answer.

Comment: @Andrey I have attached my script to question now. I run it as a Ruby program.

Comment: I am using RubyMine, you could put debug pointer there and then you can run on debug mode, you could put debugging point on loginbutton, click once it's reached then your program would wait, meanwhile you could enter the captcha manually and then by pressing the F9 button, you could allow the program to continue with rest of the execution. If you still any help from me, please give your teamviewer, I will set things for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to manually enter data:
1. Add sleep command so you can manually enter Captcha to the browser by hand:

```
sleep 30
```

2. Add gets command that will prompt user to enter captcha via console (I do not know the actual name of the captcha field):

   captcha = gets.chomp

   browser.text_field(:name, "captcha").set captcha

Comment: Thanks for this. I did not know sleep command is there is Ruby. I am new to Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

The entire point of a captcha is to prevent automated access to sites.  Typically sites which employ captcha's also have terms of service that prohibit access of their site using bots or automation of any kind.

A far better approach than trying to scrape the website is to use an API where one is provided.

IRCTC does have an API, you can get info about it here:  http://api.erail.in/

Using an api is far more reliable, much faster, and less brittle than trying to do what you want by scraping and web-automation.   I recommend also looking at the REST-CLIENT gem to facilitate making the requests and handling responses.